# Oracle Trigger when Database drive space reaches critical level

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to write a trigger than starts a data export procedure when the drive space of Oracle reaches a critical level (say 90%). One could write a Java trigger for this, but is there any PL/SQL way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Resumable Space Allocation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schema002.htm) you can register a  trigger on the AFTER SUSPEND system event.

see also the [System Events](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/search?word=System%20Events&partno=) documentation

Comment: Your link to 'Resumable Space Allocation' doesn't work - it links straight back to this question.  Would it be possible to fix it?

Comment: I changed the link so it points to the relevant chapter of the Oracle documentation.  TTMAN can correct it if that;s not their intended target.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use dbms_scheduler and poll for this event: every x minutes, the scheduler will launch a job that checks your criteria (space, whatever) and if criteria met, will run your desired actions.